# Stock data carry over to next day in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Last day closing stock should be the opening stock value of the next day.

I have tried this

```
var k = INV_STOCKs.Select(x =>
    new DemoItemV1
    {
        AreaId = x.STOCK_DATE,
        CategoryTitle = x.STOCK_QTY
    })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select((x, i) => { x.ID = i + 1; return x })
    .ToList();
```

Table structure

ID,STOCK_DATE,STOCK_QTY

Please any one can help to solve this

I need to print like this

```
  Date         Opening Stock      Closing Stock
01/01/13                  0                  5
01/02/13                  5                 10
01/03/13                 10                 15
01/04/13                 15                 22
01/05/13                 22                 30
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What was wrong with what you tried?

Comment: This query does not look like associated with question. Please explain your problem. For me it's horribly unclear.

Comment: @wudzik I need to print Date,opening stock,closing stock in it

Comment: @NavjuNav check out my answer, is that what you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"I need to print Date,opening stock,closing stock in it"*

```
INV_STOCKs.GroupBy(x=>x.STOCK_DATE).ForEach(group=>
{
   var g = group.OrderBy(x.ID);
   Print(g.First().STOCK_DATE); //Date
   Print(g.First().STOCK_QTY); //Opening stock
   Print(g.Last().STOCK_QTY); //Closing stock
});
```

Print is some method printing you this value, of course you can use one method with 3 paramameters or whatever :)

EDIT:
to store it in list:

```
class StockStore
{
   public int OpeningStock;
   public int ClosingStock;
   public DateTime Date;
}

var list = new List<StockStore>();

INV_STOCKs.GroupBy(x=>x.STOCK_DATE).ForEach(group=>
{
   var g = group.OrderBy(x.ID);
   list.Add(new StockStore 
   {
       OpeningStock = g.First().STOCK_QTY,
       ClosingStock = g.Last().STOCK_QTY,
       Date = g.First().STOCK_DATE
   }); 
});
```

Comment: i don't need to print it. I need a list that hold the whole data in the required format.

Comment: edited, now you have your opening/closing stock in stored in list

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines.

```
    var lastStockItem = INV_Stocks
         .OrderByDescending(x=>x.StOCK_Date)
         .FirstorDefault();
```

That should get you the last stock item of the day.